# Alinhas cards com texto grande na mesma linha

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo uma tela que faz uma listagem de card de usuários, porém dependendo o tamanho do texto que irá no card, ele perde a orientação e acaba "estourando" a linha.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como preciso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer que independente do texto, ele sempre irá respeitar 3 cards por linha? Nesse exemplo que coloquei, apenas deixei um tamanho fixo (height), porém quando o texto ultrapassa o tamanho, ele continua "estourando".

Meus arquivos: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n8j45vrg/)

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Uma forma de resolver esse problema seria adicionar um `clear:left;` em todos os cards que iniciam a linha. Essa propriedade fará com que esses cards sejam adicionados a uma nova linha, sem sofrer efeito do `float` aplicado ao card anterior.

Para isso, você pode remover as `divs` com a classe `my-class` e adicionar uma classe `my-card` aos cards. Depois disso você pode usar a pseudo-classe CSS `:nth-of-type` para aplicar `clear` somente aos primeiros cards de cada linha. Essa pseudo-classe permite selecionar apenas alguns elementos de um determinado tipo de acordo com a ordem em que aparecem. Leia mais sobre ela [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Eu percebi que no seu código o número de cards por linha é modificado de acordo com o tamanho da tela, logo teremos que tratar os dois casos: em que aparecem apenas dois cards por linha e quando aparecem três cards por linha.

Considere que enumeramos os cards de `1` até `N`. Quando temos apenas dois cards por linha, o início de cada linha é sempre um card ímpar e quando temos três cards por linha o início de cada linha é sempre `3n + 1`, em que `n` é o número da linha (começando de `0`).

Dessa forma, podemos usar `@media` para tratar a quantidade de cards por linha e aplicar `:nth-of-type` corretamente. Segue o css:

```css
/* com dois cards por linha */
@media (max-width: 1139px){
  .my-card:nth-of-type(odd){
    clear: left;   
  }
}

/* com três cards por linha */
@media (min-width: 1140px){
  .my-card:nth-of-type(3n+1){
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

Segue o [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx8hcavn/8/) com o exemplo que você mandou modificado.

Espero ter ajudado.